Переименовать таблицу, получив данные для нового имени из данных внутри таблицы
Дана таблица, в которой одно из полей это дата-время событий. Выглядят данные так:
2024-04-11 16:53:57.648000

Вопрос
Можно ли в одном запросе

Получить новое имя состоящее из начальной даты-конечной даты
И переименовать таблицу.

В общем случае, можно ли взять какие-то данные из таблицы и ее переименовать, используя в новом имени эти данные.
Я попытался сделать так:
WITH new_name AS (select 't_table' || '_' || replace(replace(left(min(date_time), 19), ' ', '_'), ':', '-') || '_' || 
replace(replace(left(max(date_time), 19), ' ', '_'), ':', '-') from t_table)
alter table t_table rename to (select * from new_name);

То есть, беру минимальную и максимальную дату, отрезаю дробную часть, меняю символы на допустимые (в общем, получаю новое имя). В результате получаю синтаксическую ошибку где-то рядом с ALTER.
Я могу решить это на стороне клиента - сначала получить данные для имени, потом эти данные отправить вторым запросом на переименовку. Но можно ли сделать это одним запросом?

Можно ли в одном запросе Нет. В общем случае, можно ли Да. Но нет. Надо как минимум, чтобы ВСЕ записи таблицы дали в результате одно и то же значение для нового имени таблицы.

@Akina благодарю!
